# Magento 1.9 set the order for multiple select attribute product

Tags: magento-1.9

I've created a new product attribute of type multiple select from a predefined list. 
The problem with multiple select is that I cannot set the order for the selected values into the admin panel. The order is important for the frontend. 
I've tried to create, without success, a custom renderer for this attribute.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks